# Node server returning data in debug mode but not in live mode

Tags: node.js

When I run my node server in debug mode, and execute the get function below from a GET request, it returns the data that I am expecting in about 500ms.  If I run the server in live mode and perform the same action, I get no response.

If I access the getTime function similarly, in debug mode I get the valid data in about 300ms, but in live mode I get an empty string.

I have a feeling that the problem is in how I'm handling the async, since debug mode runs just a bit slower than live mode, but that also means I can't troubleshoot this in debug mode.

```
var storage = require('../services/storage');

module.exports = {
  get: async function(req, res){
    console.log('request received.');
    let data = await getClientData();      
    let clientData = JSON.parse(data);
    if (clientData){
      console.log('returning data.');
      res.send(clientData);
    }
  }, 
  getTime: async function(req, res){
    console.log('Getting time from storage');
    let data = await getClientData(); 
    let time = JSON.parse(data).time;
    console.log('getTime: ', time);
    res.send(time);
  }
}

async function getClientData(){
  return await storage.get('clientData');
}
```

Storage module:

```
if (typeof localStorage === "undefined" 
|| localStorage === null) {
  var LocalStorage = 
    require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
  localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
}

module.exports = {
  get: async function(key){
    try {
      console.log('pulling from storage');
      let data = await localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (data !== null && data !== ''
      && typeof data !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('data has been pulled');
        return data;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        'Unable to get ' + key + ' from localStorage!'
      );
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('the localstorage if statement failed to run');
  },
  set: function(key, value){
    try {
      console.log('Saving to localStorage');
      let objectToStore = {
        data: value,
        time: new Date()
      };
      let stringToStore = 
        JSON.stringify(objectToStore);
      localStorage.setItem(
        key, 
        stringToStore
        );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        'Error while saving to localStorage!'
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

I've added in some console statements to help track the flow, and made some changes based on comments.  Still having the same issue. Based on the console output, it looks like the getTime function is proceeding without waiting for the storage module's get function to return.

Debug console output (both examples are calling getTime function):

```
Getting time from storage
pulling from storage
data has been pulled
getTime:  2018-02-09T14:12:05.141Z
```

Live console output:

```
Getting time from storage
pulling from storage
getTime:  undefined
```

Comment: Why are you using await infront of `JSON.parse`

Comment: I'm trying to parse the data pulled from storage into JSON and then grab the value from the "time" key inside it.

Comment: You don't have to use await for that. await is for async calls

Comment: Good point.  It's bad practice to try multiple things at the same time.  But, even if I refactor it so that it awaits pulling the data first and then JSON.parse that pulled data, I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node-localstorage module uses a different location in debug mode.  In debug mode, it was saving to the same path as the package.json file, but in live mode it was using the path of the server.js file.

The reason why I was getting an empty string as a response is because the data I was testing with had been built in debug mode, and did not exist in the path the live mode was using.

Building the data in live mode resolved the issue.